# Which iPhone app version do I see on my iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, testing

I have an iPhone app which has been coded to be optimised for the various iPhone screen dimensions and resolutions. I have not included an iPad version.

When I view this app on an iPad Air 2, which version will I be seeing? The version optimised for an iPhone 6 Plus? Or something else?

(My reason for asking this question is that I don't have an iPhone 6 or 6 Plus to test on so I'm wondering if my iPad can do the job for me. I'm mainly interested in seeing the layout and image resolutions).

Comment: is it not possible to use a virtual device for testing purposes when you create a iphone app?

Comment: Are you using size classes?

Comment: I believe you will see the iPhone 4 version either at 1x resolution (with lots of black space around it) or at 2x resolution (pixels expanded to fill the iPad screen).

Comment: What do you mean by a 'virtual device'?

Comment: @MissSarah746482 The iOS Simulator.

Comment: @NobodyNada I have two concerns about using the simulator. 1) Is it 100% reliable as an exact replica of what you'd see on a phone? 2) Will I get a true representation of how image resolutions would appear on an iPhone 6 screen when I'm looking at the simulator on my seven year old MacBook?

Comment: @MissSarah746482 The simulator is not exactly the same as a phone (it is much faster, for example), but it should give you the same result as a device for this.